# oTree - modify the 'Configure Session' segment dynamically

Tags: python, django, otree

I recently started using oTree to build an [extensive-form game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensive-form_game), and I want to be able to determine the role of each participant in each round when creating a session.

Is it possible to change the `SESSION_CONFIGS` dictionary dynamically (depends on the number of participants and the number of rounds) so I'll be able to configure the roles of the participants online, or should I configure that using [Treatments](https://otree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/treatments.html)?

Thanks.

Comment: you can do it, but I see no reason why you would need it if oTree has a mechanism to assign roles dynamically, using role() method. See more here: https://otree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#role

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski thanks for the answer. Using `role()` is a good approach too, but I prefer the admin will be able to assign roles _online_ and not using a configuration file which i'll probably need if I follow your answer. I guess that if my preferred approach  will be too messy I'll follow yours, though.

Comment: well, you can do it by adding an extra model, and an extra url via an otree extension (search for EXTENSION_APPS keyword in otree documentation). It's not the easiest thing to do though, so if you get stuck, let me know. As a starting point have a look here: https://github.com/chapkovski/gettier, specifically at the urls.py. This code is pretty old, and it should be done differently with a newer version of oTree though

Answer (score 0):

May be session.vars?
Worked for me, I used it to assign groups to different treatments.